# Does Jetpack Compose use Espresso for Instrumented testing?

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

I am new to Android Testing and looking at testing my jetpack Compose based app. I am trying to understand the instrumentation test framework and struggling with how the compose testing architecture works.

A lot of the pain comes from how `idling resources` work. However, as idling resources is used in `Espresso` which is mainly based on View system, I would like to understand if my compose app needs to use Espresso for testing? Or is Espresso redundant when it comes to compose testing and I do not need to worry about it?